# How to correct Apache2 Ubuntu Default page showing in place of Gitlab

Tags: apache, configuration, installation, gitlab, default

I'm trying to get Gitlab running on my Ubuntu server which already has Apache2 running.

I first installed it per https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu?version=ce, then I followed these directions https://ryansechrest.com/2015/08/use-apache-instead-of-built-in-nginx-in-gitlab-ce/ but instead of getting the Gitlab setup page, I'm getting Apache2 default page.

The URL looks to be properly redirected. However, when I look into the DocumentRoot directory `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public` I don't see an index page. I can access the deploy.html page from the URL. My guess it's not fully installed. But I'm not sure.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you don't have Apache or Nginx installed on your host when you install Gitlab.

To find out if a package is installed:

`dpkg -l | grep -e apache -e nginx`

If this is not the reason, can you show the content of your /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file? 
Can you also check that everything is running with this command:

`gitlab-ctl status`

If not can you check your gitlab log files for errors in /var/log/gitlab/